# LINQ & Enums as IQueryable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, enums, iqueryable

I basically have an enum

```
public enum WorkingDays
    {
        Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday
    }
```

and would like to do a comparison against an input, which happens to be a string

```
//note lower case
string input = "monday";
```

The best thing I could come up with was something like this

```
WorkingDays day = (from d in Enum.GetValues(typeof(WorkingDays)).Cast<WorkingDays>()
                               where d.ToString().ToLowerInvariant() == input.ToLowerInvariant()
                               select d).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there any better way to do it ?

Edit: Thanks Aaron & Jason. But what if the parse fails  ?

```
if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(WorkingDay),input))//cannot compare if case is different
            {
                WorkingDay day = (WorkingDay)Enum.Parse(typeof(WorkingDay), input, true);
                Console.WriteLine(day);
            }
```

Comment: See 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9.aspx
for the exceptions that can be thrown.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you trying to convert a `string` to an instance of `WorkingDays`? If so use [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx):

```
WorkingDays day = (WorkingDays)Enum.Parse(typeof(WorkingDays), "monday", true);
```

Here we are using the overload [`Enum.Parse(Type, string, bool)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9.aspx) where the `bool` parameter indicates whether or not to ignore case.

On a side note, you should rename `WorkingDays` to `WorkingDay`. Look at like this. When you have an instance of `WorkingDay`, say,

```
WorkingDay day = WorkingDay.Monday;
```

note that `day` is a working day (thus `WorkingDay`) and not working days (thus not `WorkingDays`). For additional guidelines on naming enumerations, see [Enumeration Type Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x252001(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://blogs.msdn.com/tims/archive/2004/04/02/106310.aspx) a non-Linq way.

EDIT: It's basically Jason's way. He posted before me. Give the kudos to him.

Answer (score 1):

use IsDefined
[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx)

Comment: Actually, using IsDefined isn't the best way to go for range checks like this. (Framework Design Guidelines, 2nd Ed., pp 181-182). Enum.IsDefined is deceptively expensive due to a lot of reflection and it isn't guaranteed to always yield the correct results for the call site.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert an enum into a IQueryable by populating a List collection.

```
// Create list to hold enum values
List<string> WorkingDaysList = new List<string>();

// loop thru enum values and store in List
foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(WorkingDays)))
{
    var _WorkingDaysList = ((WorkingDays)value).ToString();
    WorkingDaysList.Add(_WorkingDaysList);
}
// use linq to query list       
var result = (from d in WorkingDaysList where d.ToLower() == input.ToLower() select d).FirstOrDefault();
```